# Where is Rust's range indexing behavior documented?

Tags: rust, indexing, range, slice, panic

In Rust, if you attempt to index a slice with a "backwards" `Range<usize>` , the program panics:

```rust
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
let slice = &arr[4..1]; // panic: slice index starts at 4 but ends at 1
```

This behavior is unsurprising, but not obvious: a reasonable alternative behavior would be to just return the empty slice `&[]`. This is what python does.

The documentation for [Index::index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) states that the indexing operation "May panic if the index is out of bounds", but doesn't define what it means to be "out of bounds". I'd argue that in this example, the range `4..1` is actually **not** out-of-bounds for an array of size 7 because both 4 and 1 are less than 7, and therefore the panic behavior here is wrong and returning the empty slice `&[]` is a more reasonable behavior than panicking, given how the documentation is worded.

Is there somewhere in the documentation that clearly defines the behavior of `Index<Range<usize>> for [T]`? Specifically, I feel like the documentation should make explicitly clear that this panics if either of the following are true:

1. `range.end > slice.len()`
2. `range.end < range.start`

Also the documentation should make clear that this **does** panic, not just that it might, because surely this panic is not UB.

Comment: Just for the record, we know `Index::index` does not invoke UB simply by it not being `unsafe`, secondly not just is "this panic [..] not UB" `panic`ing is **never** UB.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not documented for slices (you are welcomed to send a PR), but at least it's documented for `str`, in the trait that powers indexing: [`SliceIndex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html#impl-SliceIndex%3Cstr%3E-for-Range%3Cusize%3E):

> ## Panics
>
> Panics if `begin` or `end` does not point to the starting byte offset of
> a character (as defined by `is_char_boundary`), if `begin > end`, or if
> `end > len`.

Comment: I noticed that too. It's good that this is documented here, but I think this documentation gap is still an issue because it's not safe for a user to assume anything about `impl SliceIndex<[T]> for Range<usize>` based on the behavior of `impl SliceIndex<str> for Range<usize>` as these are two completely different implementations.